# How to add an additional user in iMessage?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, imessage

I have a simple idea for an iMessage app. It would need to function where there is a specific contact in iMessage (think like how "Apple" support has its own dedicated one), where you can send messages to it and they are received by the backend.

Is it possible to do this with the iOS tools? How can one achieve this using the Xcode toolkit for iOS development?

Comment: Are you looking business chat https://www.apple.com/au/ios/business-chat/ ?

Comment: It seems like it @Paulw11 . I don't think they would approve me though. I'd like for it to be a way to talk to ChatGPT via its API